# Tool bar icons in the source

Tags: source-code

I am looking for tool bar icon files either .svg or in any other picture format. But I couldn't find them.
Other icons are in the blender_icons.svg file in "release\datafiles" 
Where are the tool bar icons ?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This thread should help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165109/78972

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply !